# How to use Get-Azmetrics to get Storage Account UsedCapacity for a specific date?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-powershell

Is there a way to use the Get-Azmetrics command to get the UsedCapacity for a Storage Account for a specific date or between dates?

I can use the below command to get it for a specific timespan but what about on a specific date?

```
(Get-AzMetric -ResourceId "your_resource_id" -MetricName "UsedCapacity" -AggregationType Average -StartTime "02:00:00" -EndTime "04:00:00").Data
```

Comment: @RajkumarMamidiChettu-MT Is there no way to get this information for a specific date? I can browse back from within the portal/metrics panel but it can be quite cumbersome to keep select "back" until you finally get to the date you are looking for. I'm also assuming that if this data exists it must be stored somewhere?

Comment: sorry for the confusion here looks like we can pass 'time+date' to the start time and end time parameters as explained in the example-4 in this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.monitor/get-azmetric?view=azps-8.1.0#example-4-get-summarized-output-for-a-specified-metric-with-specified-dimension-filter)

Comment: @RajkumarMamidiChettu-MT I'm not having much luck getting it to work. I keep getting "Operation returned an invalid status code 'BadRequest'". If you have some time would appreciate it if you tried it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get data for a specific date and time period, you just need to specify date/time value in `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ` format in `-StartTime` and `-EndTime` parameters. For example, look the command below. It fetches the data for 1st of July 2022 between midnight and 2:00 AM UTC.

```
(Get-AzMetric -ResourceId "resource-id" -MetricName "UsedCapacity" -StartTime 2022-07-01T00:00:00Z -EndTime 2022-07-01T02:00:00Z).Data
```

and here's the output it produced:

```
TimeStamp : 7/31/2022 12:00:00 AM
Average   : 4093594
Minimum   : 
Maximum   : 
Total     : 
Count     : 

TimeStamp : 7/31/2022 1:00:00 AM
Average   : 4094605
Minimum   : 
Maximum   : 
Total     : 
Count     :
```

Comment: Thanks Gaurav, the mistake I was making was setting the date too far in the past!